# I lost all my user settings on Mac OS X! But the user is still there in the Users folder

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

Ok, I ran into a major problem. I was trying to set a default folder for Terminal to start up in (which unfortunately I still haven't been able to figure out). Instead, all my settings related to the user settings (e.g. spaces, docks, iTunes playlists, desktop) have all reverted back to the default setting.

If I were to log out of my Mac OS X 10.6.7 system, I still see my user account name and "Other". I log in under my user account name with my User ID "GabbAHH" and I enter my profile except of course it shows a default desktop, etc. Now when I open Finder, under Places it says "GC" (it looks like I attempted to change to this name, see below) instead of GabbAHH. If I were to go to my Users folder, I still see GabbAHH, and Shared (and nothing else). This GabbAHH folder still contains all my desktop files.

This is what I believe I did:

From this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145321/how-to-set-os-x-terminals-default-home) I have clicked on [this link](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071025175202466).

I foolishly attempted the steps described in the link even though it says 10.5 only (I have 10.6.7). Following the instructions I hit:

```
dscl localhost
```

Inside dscl I typed:

```
cd /Local/Default/Users
```

Then for the instructions:

```
change someuser dsAttrTypeNative:home /Users/someuser /Volumes/path/to/new/home/someuser
```

I typed:

```
change GabbAHH dsAttrTypeNative:home /Users/GabbAHH /Users/GabbAHH/'Rails Projects'/GC
```

This gave me an error of some sort that I do not remember (I think it may have stated something about dsAttrTypeNative not defined/found). I didn't think much about it at the time since I didn't think typing this has affected any of my User settings due to the error. However, I'm still not completely sure if this is the cause.

At this point I don't want to go back into dscl and try reverting it in case I end up in a deeper hole.

Does anyone know how I can revert back to my original GabbAHH user profile? I have my fingers crossed that it can be done since my files still appear to be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open System Preferences, Accounts preference pane, right-click on your user and set the path to your home directory there. Much more convenient.